# Push notification when device come back to online state

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Is there a way where I can get all the push notifications triggered to a device during its offline state while coming back online ? I know in documentation it is mentioned that only last notification will be received. But is there a work around or some mechanism where the the device can get all the push notifications when coming back online ? I have seen in Whatsapp application that they do get all the push notifications after coming online. Was wondering how that would be happening for them. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.